# How to find the first empty row in an HTML table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code example below creates a table with 6 rows. The last two rows are empty. 
The JavaScript code finds and displays correctly the number of rows in a table.

I would like to find the row number of the first row with empty cells. In this example it will be row (4) (counting from 0). I tried several solutions and they did not work.

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Menachem

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 3</td>
    <td>cell 4</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>cell 4</td>
    <td>cell 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br> 

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;
alert ("Number of rows in the table is " + x);          
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use combination of **[`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)** and **[`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)**.

1. `td:not(:empty)` get td which is not empty
2. `tr:not(:has(td:not(:empty)))` selects all tr which is not contains any non empty `td`
3. `tr:not(:has(td:not(:empty))):first` gets the first `tr` from them

```js
var index = $("#myTable tr:not(:has(td:not(:empty))):first").index();
console.log(index);
```

```css
table,td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 3</td>
    <td>cell 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 4</td>
    <td>cell 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>

<script>
  var x = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;
  alert("Number of rows in the table is " + x);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to find the row number of the first row with empty cells

You can use `:has()`, adjacent sibling selector `+` to match `td:empty`, that has next element sibling that is `td:empty`, `:first`, `index()`. The index of the first `tr` element which has a child `td` element without child nodes would be `3`

```
$("#myTable tr:has(td:empty + td:empty):first").index()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>cell 1</td>
      <td>cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell 3</td>
      <td>cell 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell 4</td>
      <td>cell 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>

  <script>
    var x = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;
    alert("Number of rows in the table is " + x);
    console.log($("#myTable tr:has(td:empty + td:empty):first").index());
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Won't this simply find the first row that has any td being empty? From: _"first row with empty __cells__"_, and title including _"first empty row"_ sounds like they are looking for the tr that has _all_ tds being empty

Comment: @PatrickEvans :`$("#myTable tr:not(:has(td:not(:empty))):first").index()`

Comment: @PranavCBalan You can also use adjacent sibling selector `+`

Comment: @guest271314 : in case there is three column , you need to use another `+`

Comment: @PranavCBalan _"in case there is three column"_ You could use general sibling selector `~` called on first empty `td`

Comment: @guest271314 : that will also skip element, please check that

Comment: @PranavCBalan _"that will also skip element"_ Which element would it skip? Though, note, "in case there is three column" does not appear at OP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112218/discussion-between-pranav-c-balan-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#myTable tr").find('td').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == '' ;
}).addClass('empty');
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.empty {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 3</td>
    <td>cell 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 4</td>
    <td>cell 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Use .filter()

Answer (score 0):

You can use a test inside a [.filter()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) call that checks the number of empty `td`'s against the number of all `td`'s in a `tr`. Filter out all those that have any non-empty `td`, call [.first()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to find the first one in the filtered set, and [.index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to get the index

```js
var index = $("#myTable tr").filter(function(){
   return $("td",this).length == $("td:empty",this).length;;
}).first().index();

console.log("Empty row index: "+index);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 3</td>
    <td>cell 4</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>cell 4</td>
    <td>cell 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```